# Is there a way to use data validation in google sheets to fill two cells with one input, dictionary-style?

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I'm using google sheets, and the built-in Data > Validation function.

What I'd like to do is create a list of products in column A, and their respective prices in Column B, EG:

Product 1 - $100

Product 2 - $200

Product 3 - $300

And then I'd like to use Validation with "list from a range", so that if I select "Product 1" in column C, its price will be dropped into column D.

Is this possible in google sheets, using either conditional formatting, data validation, or any other means?

The end result would also have a "Quantity" column and a "Total" column, which multiplies "Quantity" by whatever price is in Column C, and gives me a line total, eg "Product 1" - "$100" - "Qty: 3" - "Line total: $300", but that's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en). For example, if the dictionary is in the range A1:B5, and the dropdown in C1, then

```
=iferror(vlookup(C1, A1:B5, 2, false))
```

will return the corresponding price. Explanation:

- look up the value of C1
- in the first column of range A1:B5
- return the value in the second column (2)
- do not assume A is sorted (false)
- do not show an error message if there is no match (iferror)